# How can I change the size of the wordcloud in R shiny to do not to cut the image?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change the size of the wordcloud in `R` shiny to do not to cut the image?

I used `png()` function, but I did not get results :

[image]

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    terms2 <- reactive({
      # Change when the "update" button is pressed...
      input$update

      data2 <- input$texto1

      # ...but not for anything else
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
          getTermMatrix2(data2)

        })
      })
    })

    v2 <- terms2()

    wordcloud_rep2(names(v2), v2, scale=c(4,0.5),
                  min.freq = 1, max.words=20,
                  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })
```

Comment: I used "height = 700". 
plotOutput("plot",width = "100%",height=700

Answer (score 0):

Use wordcloud2 instead of wordcloud.
its basic need is two columns word and frequency to render the wordcloud,
also it has has its own renderoutput and renderwordcloud in shiny.
i have attached the example have a look.

```
this is how your data should look like:

   words   freq
   oil     85
   said    73
   prices  48
```

[wordcloud2 link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html)

```
   library(wordcloud2)
   library(shiny)
   library(shinydashboard)

 ui <- dashboardPage(
       dashboardHeader(),
         dashboardSidebar(),
           dashboardBody(
               wordcloud2Output('cloud')
            )
          ) 

    server <- function(input, output) {
       output$cloud <- renderWordcloud2({
        wordcloud2(demoFreq)
     })
    }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this HAVE to use shiny dashboard?